# Python argparse: Combine optional parameters with nargs=argparse.REMAINDER

Tags: python, argparse

I must be missing something obvious. The goal is to use argparse with the first parameter required, a second optional and any other remaining parameters optional.

To show the issue I made two test parsers; the only difference between them is using nargs=argparse.REMAINDER in one and nargs='*' in the other.

```
def doParser1(argsin):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Parser demo.')
    parser.add_argument('req1', help='first required parameter')
    parser.add_argument('--opt1', help='first optional parameter')
    parser.add_argument('leftovers', nargs=argparse.REMAINDER,
                    help='all the other parameters')
    argsout = parser.parse_args(args=argsin)
    print argsout
    return argsout

def doParser2(argsin):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Parser demo.')
    parser.add_argument('req1', help='first required parameter')
    parser.add_argument('--opt1', help='first optional parameter')
    parser.add_argument('leftovers', nargs='*',
                    help='all the other parameters')
    argsout = parser.parse_args(args=argsin)
    print argsout
    return argsout
```

If there are no extra parameters, parser2 works. This is the input followed by parser1 and parser 1:

```
input: ['req1value', '--opt1', 'opt1value']
Namespace(leftovers=['--opt1', 'opt1value'], opt1=None, req1='req1value')
Namespace(leftovers=None, opt1='opt1value', req1='req1value')
```

If there are extra parameters, the opt1 value is missed in parser1 and parser2 just gets confused:

```
input: ['req1value', '--opt1', 'opt1value', 'r1', 'r2']
Namespace(leftovers=['--opt1', 'opt1value', 'r1', 'r2'], opt1=None, req1='req1value')
usage: py-argparse.py [-h] [--opt1 OPT1]
                  [-leftovers [LEFTOVERS [LEFTOVERS ...]]]
                  req1
py-argparse.py: error: unrecognized arguments: r1 r2
```

The expected output should be:

```
Namespace(leftovers=['r1', 'r2'], opt1='opt1value', req1='req1value')
```

It seems this should be a simple case and what is here is simplified from what I'm really trying to do. I've tried making leftovers optional, adding a variety of other options, but nothing works any better.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`--opt1` needs to come before "unnamed" arguments.  Your real test cases should be:

```
    ['--opt1', 'opt1value', 'req1value']
```

and

```
    ['--opt1', 'opt1value', 'req1value', 'r1', 'r2']
```

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple. I didn't see that in the docs anywhere, but it works for the nargs=argparse.REMAINDER, and that's all I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `parse_known_args`:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Parser demo.')
parser.add_argument('req1', help='first required parameter')
parser.add_argument('--opt1', help='first optional parameter')

args, leftovers = parser.parse_known_args(['req1value', '--opt1', 'opt1value'])
print(args, leftovers)
# (Namespace(opt1='opt1value', req1='req1value'), [])

args, leftovers = parser.parse_known_args(['req1value', '--opt1', 'opt1value', 'r1', 'r2'])
print(args, leftovers)
# (Namespace(opt1='opt1value', req1='req1value'), ['r1', 'r2'])
```

Comment: I'll file this away for later. The other answer suited what I need. It looks like this solution doesn't require the options to be first, is that right?

Comment: Right. This will accept the arguments in any order. Those that don't match end up in `leftovers`.

Comment: Nice solution. However, the former *remainder* will no longer show up in the documentation / help.

Comment: Thanks for this!  I was a bit disappointed when I ran into this exact issue and found in the accepted answer that I would be forced to put the optional parameters first (which, in my case, is completely counterintuitive and annoying). This provides a nicer handling.

Answer (score 2):

The inter mixing of positionals and optionals is tricky when one or more of the positionals is of the 'zero or more' type (`? * REMAINDER`).   The simple solution is to not mix them - give the optionals first, then all the positionals afterwards.

Here's what's going on:

```
input: ['req1value', '--opt1', 'opt1value']
Namespace(leftovers=['--opt1', 'opt1value'], opt1=None, req1='req1value')
```

Because of the `req1value` string the parser first parses for positionals.  `req1` wants 1 string, `leftovers` grabs everything else including `--opt1`.

```
Namespace(leftovers=None, opt1='opt1value', req1='req1value')
```

With `*` `leftovers` is satisfied with `[]`, no string, hence `None` (actually I get `[]`).  `--opt1` is parsed as an optional.

```
input: ['req1value', '--opt1', 'opt1value', 'r1', 'r2']
...
py-argparse.py: error: unrecognized arguments: r1 r2
```

As before `*` `leftovers` is set to `[]`.  `-opt1` is processed.  But now there are 2 strings with no place to put them.  You intended them to go into `leftovers`, but that was already used.  If `leftovers` was `+` it would have taken them  as you intended.

The key is that when it tries to parse the 1st positional, it also tries to parse all the positionals that it can.   At one level `parse_args` is doing `re.match('(A)(A*)','AOA')` producing groups `('A', '')`.

There are 2 proposed patches that deal with this issue.  One uses the 2 step `parse_known_args` to allow a complete mixing of optionals and positionals.  This is the kind of behavior that users of `optparse` might have come to expect.

The other patch tries to delay the handling of positionals that can accept `0` argument strings http://bugs.python.org/issue15112 .