# How to access optional parameter in this case?

Tags: python, argparse

How to access optional parameter in this case?

I have a parser like

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='some_prog',formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter)
parser.add_argument("tableName")
parser.add_argument("--duration",help = """It is an optional parameter.""")
parser.add_argument("columns",nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)
args = parser.parse_args()
print args.duration
```

When I execute "python some_prog.py T1 --duration=1278678-3275678678 column1 column2" using command prompt

args.duration is returning None

How can I access "duration"?

Please suggest me the solution...

Please let me know if the way I am using for nargs is wrong?

Comment: This exact code works just fine for me (adding an `import argparse` at the top of the file).  What version of python are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the optional arguments first:

```
python some_prog.py --duration=1278678-3275678678 T1 column1 column2
```

works well for me.

T1 will get assigned to `tableName`, while "column1 column2" will get assigned to `columns`

This is because after getting the positional argument `tableName`, it will take the rest as part of `argparse.REMAINDER`.

I remember seeing this in another SO question, but I couldn't find it.

To make it possible to put your `tableName` as first argument, you can use [`parse_known_args`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#partial-parsing) instead of `parse_args` and remove the definition of `column`:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='some_prog',formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter)
parser.add_argument("tableName")
parser.add_argument("--duration",help = """It is an optional parameter.""")

(args, the_rest) = parser.parse_known_args()
print args.tableName
print args.duration
print the_rest
```

which will give:

```
T1
1234
['column1', 'column2']
```

Comment: is there any way to change the order? so that first it will take tableName, duration and then others

Comment: You can use `parse_known_args` for that. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

The resulting namespace is:

```
Namespace(columns=['--duration=1278678-3275678678', 'column1', 'column2'], duration=None, tableName='T1')
```

`columns` grabbed everything, the `REMAINDER`.

If I give it: `"--duration=1278678-3275678678 T1 column1 column2"`, I get:

```
Namespace(columns=['--duration=1278678-3275678678', 'column1', 'column2'], duration=None, tableName='T1')
```

Let's change the `nargs=REMAINDER` to `nargs='*'`.  Now the first case gives

```
error: unrecognized arguments: column1 column2
```

The issue is how a positional that can take zero or more values is consumed. See this SO discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18645430/901925 `'Python argparse: Combine optional parameters with nargs=argparse.REMAINDER.`

In short `columns` either consumes everything after `T1`, or it consumes the `[]` between `T1` and `--duration`.

Change it to `nargs='+'`, and it works.  Why?  Because it has to match one or more strings. Now it does not fit into the gap.

The issue has been raised in other SO threads, and on Python bugs (intermixing optionals and positionals)

But in the meantime your choices are:

- put optionals like `--duration` before positionals
- use '+' instead of '*' or 'REMAINDER'
- parse the input in a couple of steps.